# A problem about the strictly convex function on $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F:\mathbf R\rightarrow \mathbf R$ be a strictly convex function, $u:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbf R$ continuous. Suppose $$\int\limits_{0}^{1} u(x) \ dx=0.$$ Show that $$\int\limits_{0}^{1} F(u(x)) \ dx\le\frac{F(\|u\|_\infty)+F(-\|u\|_\infty)}{2}$$ and find when the equality holds.

I think that I should apply the Jensen equality. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: let $\|u\|_\infty = m$.  Then for $-m \le t \le m$,
$$F(t) \le   \frac{m-t}{2m} F(-m) + \frac{t+m}{2m} F(m)$$
Substitute $t = u(x)$ and integrate.

Comment: thank you very much